# Value of type 'Item' has no member 'parentCategory'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have 2 entities

[image]

I'm using XCode 10 right now, I am not sure if I did something wrong or XCode bug.

I added 1 line into these lines

```
let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
newItem.title = textField.text!
newItem.done = false
newItem.parentCategory = self.selectedCategory <--------- ADD HERE 
self.itemArray.append(newItem)
self.saveItems()
```

[image]

Any hints for me on why this is happening ?

## TodoListVC

```
//
//  TodoListVC
//  ListHue
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class TodoListVC: UITableViewController {

    var itemArray = [Item]()
    
    var selectedCategory : Category? {
        didSet {
            loadItems()
        }
    }
    
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - viewDidLoad
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print(FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask))
        
        
    }
    

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Datasource
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemArray.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "listItemCell", for: indexPath)
        let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
        cell.accessoryType = item.done == true ? .checkmark : .none
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Delegate
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        context.delete(itemArray[indexPath.row])
        itemArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        
        
        itemArray[indexPath.row].done = !itemArray[indexPath.row].done
        
        self.saveItems()
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Add new item
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       
        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Item", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        //action
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Item", style: .default) { (action) in
    
            
            let newItem = Item(context: self.context)
            newItem.title = textField.text!
            newItem.done = false
            newItem.parentCategory = self.selectedCategory
            self.itemArray.append(newItem)
            self.saveItems()
           
            
        }
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Model Manipulation Methods
    
    
    func saveItems() {
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context, \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }

    func loadItems(with request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()) {
        
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentCategory.name MATCHES %@", selectedCategory?.name!)
        request.predicate = predicate

        do {
            itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from the context, \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    

}

//MARK: - Search bar methods

extension TodoListVC : UISearchBarDelegate {
    func  searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchBar.text!)
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

        loadItems(with: request)
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
            
            loadItems()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

## CategoryVC

```
//
//  CategoryVC.swift
//  ListHue
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreData

class CategoryVC: UITableViewController {
    
    var categories = [Category]()
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        loadCategories()

    }
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Table View Datasource
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell", for: indexPath)
        let category = categories[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = category.name

        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Table View Delegate Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToItems", sender: self)
    
    }
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! TodoListVC
        
        //get the category of the selected cell
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            
            //set the property
            destinationVC.selectedCategory = categories[indexPath.row]
            
        }
        
    }
    

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Data Manipulation Methods
    
    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        print("click")
        
        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add New Category", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        //action
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add Category", style: .default) { (action) in
            
            let newCategory = Category(context: self.context)
            newCategory.name = textField.text!
            self.categories.append(newCategory)
            self.saveCategories()
        }
        
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            alertTextField.placeholder = "Create new item"
            textField = alertTextField
        }
        
        alert.addAction(action)
        
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
        
    }
    
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //MARK - Add New Categories
    func saveCategories() {
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Error saving context, \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    func loadCategories(with request: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()) {
        
        do {
            categories = try context.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("Error fetching data from the context, \(error)")
        }
        
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What's the code of `Item` and `Category` generated by XCode? It should help you point out the issue. `Item` should have a properties `items` which can be filled with object of `Category`.

Comment: I don't get your question at all. `What's the code of Item and Category generated by XCode?` How do I get that ? Do you want to see CategoryVC ? I can upload that also.

Comment: Where is defined `Item`? Where is defined `Category`? If you click on it to see their definition holding some key at the same time, will it leads you somewhere? You don't have to generate the files nowadays?

Comment: I defined those 2 entities in my `DataModel.xcdatamodeld ` - see here : https://pasteboard.co/Hxk8Uad.png

Comment: Open `DataModel.xcdatamodeld` and select one entity for example `Item` and check what you have in the right pane under `Codegen`

Comment: @Ladislav : I have it as class definition.

Comment: Change the editor Style. Now List the properties of each Class. Like you would with `class MyClass { var someVar: String; }` etc. What's the name of `Item` property that link it to `Category`?

Comment: @Larme : I went to the directory of my app. This is all the files I see and have. which one you want me to look at ? https://pasteboard.co/HxkaL6G.png

Comment: Command tap on `newItem.done` on the `done` part

Comment: It should open `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift` file that was autogenerated, and you will most likely see that `parentCategory` is not defined there...

Comment: @Ladislav : What is the path to that ? `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift`

Comment: `you will most likely see that parentCategory is not defined there` -- how do I fix it ?

Comment: Build and run again and if it does not fix it, copy what you have in `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift` that was autogenerated and add it to your project as a file and change `codegen` to `Manual/None` and then you can add it yourself...

Comment: I can't even build, because it is `error`.

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: I can not share this `Item+CoreDataProperties.swift` with you guys if I don't know the path to get it. Do you know ? Can you share the path to it ?

Comment: Do the following...comment out `newItem.parentCategory` line, then build. Once it builds it will probably regenerate files as needed and then you will be able to uncomment the line and it should work

Comment: XCode, will say `Build Fail` with this error `Value of type 'Item' has no member 'parentCategory'`

Comment: Now that is better.

Comment: Whenever you change something in CoreData model, first run the app, then make changes in the app and use new relationships and properties, that way codegen will create all necessary categories for you to have new stuff ready

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: When I uncomment that line, it compiles again.

Comment: But when you uncomment does `parentCategory` line compile?

Comment: But this is all I have ... https://pasteboard.co/HxkgHL0.png

Comment: When I uncomment, I can not compile. ...

Comment: And if you do `newItem.items`, does the compiler yells at you?

Comment: @Larme: Yes, I can not do that also.

Comment: I followed this course, and the instructor did it like that. https://pasteboard.co/HxkigUz.png

I don't know why and how here XCode is showing 0 error...

Comment: I tried to opened up in the XCode 9 and XCode 10, they both show the same error on that line as soon as I added.

Comment: Strangely, you should be able to do so. `let subitems = newItem.items` should work according to your CoreData Model.

Comment: `let subitems = newItem.items` this line is okay.

Comment: So, should I use that line in stead.  ?

Comment: When I type `newItem.` I don't see `parentCategory` coming up as a suggested option as these would : `done`, `title` -- something wrong.

Comment: I missed registered something somewhere. Let me know, if you guys spot it. thansk

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you from the start: `Item` doesn't have a property named `parentCategory`, it has a property `items`. It's like saying why can't you do `let str = String(); string.kyo = "Kyo"` It doesn't work like that, the compiler will throws you the same error. In CoreData, I think you misnamed `parentCategory` and `items`, `parentCategory` should be on the `Item` column.

Comment: Let me double check and please let me know what can I provide more on coredata to know the root cause.

Comment: I have it backward. Doing it like this now, works : https://pasteboard.co/Hxktv56.png You can answer it. you deserved it. Thank-you both of you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the diagram backward, thanks to @Larme, and @Ladislav helped me to know that.

[image]